Trying to Dynamically Create Tkinter Entry Widgets, but they are not showing up on screen
I am trying to dynamically create entry widgets for a poker game such that players can place their bets for the round. I have a button created to start the betting which is shown below.
betButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Bets for the round", command= lambda:[trackMoney(), betButton.destroy()])
betButton.pack()

And here is the trackMoney method
def trackMoney():
    '''Counts the money in the pot and the money for each player'''
    global currentBet, currentBets, hasRaised, entry
    currentBet = 0
    currentBets = []
    hasRaised = []
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        hasRaised.append(False)
        has_folded.append(False)
        currentBets.append(0)

    for i in range(len(cards)):
        if has_folded[i]:
            continue
        else:
            if not hasRaised[i]:
                entry = Entry(root, textvariable= "Do you choose to raise, check, or fold?")
                entry.pack()
                if entry.get() == "Raise":
                    entry.selection_clear()
                    entry.config(textvariable= "How much do you want to raise by?")
                    currentBet = int(entry.get())
                    hasRaised[i] = True
                    money[i] = money[i] - (currentBet - currentBets[i])
                    currentBets[i] = currentBet
                elif entry.get() == "Check":
                    entry.selection_clear()
                    money[i] = money[i] - (currentBet - currentBets[i])
                    currentBets[i] = currentBet
                elif entry.get() == "Fold":
                    entry.selection_clear()
                    has_folded[i] = True
            else:
                if entry.get() == "Check":
                    entry.selection_clear()
                    money[i] = money[i] - (currentBet - currentBets[i])
                    currentBets[i] = currentBet
                elif entry.get() == "Fold":
                    entry.selection_clear()
                    has_folded[i] = True
    for index in range(len(image_listHand)):
        button_list[index].config(text = getPlayerMoney(index // 2))


Whenever I press the button however, none of the entries show up. I was thinking about making them come up on a pop up window. Is there any way for me to fix this?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

using list to execute two functions in lambda is not preferred method - create normal function with trackMoney(), betButton.destroy() and assign it to command=. And later you can put print() to see if they are executed.

When I fix the parts of your code that are missing, the entries show up for me. Your problem cannot be reproduced with the code you've posted.

I figured out the issue, it seemed to be the size of my root and canvas not allowing the entry to be seen, so I modified it such that it fit in the allotted space.
